# Replacing qWait with QTimer in a desktop program

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt6, qtimer

My code:

```
def up_btn_func(self):
    if self.real_date > 1 and self.amount > 1:
        self.real_date = self.real_date - 1
    self.setup_dates()
    self.log_data()
    QtTest.QTest.qWait(120)
    self.up_btn.setChecked(False)
```

I am using `qWait()` in my method to get some time delay. I know about `QTimer singleshot`  but I need to get delay without calling new method there. What can I correctly use instead of `qWait`?

Comment: What is the reason for which you couldn't call another function? You're already doing it, it's `setChecked()`, just do it with a lambda.

Comment: I have another methods with huge amount of code lines after qWait and that's why i can't use QTimer.singleshot

Comment: Sorry but that is not a sufficient explanation, and we cannot provide arbitrary answers without sufficient details, risking to give wrong suggestions. Please take your time to read [ask], review the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648) and then [edit] your question to better explain what you're trying to do, possibly by providing an appropriate [mre] in the meantime.

Comment: Qt is event based system. You don't ever want to block the event loop. So just don't do that. Use timer. Write separate methods for things you want to do at separate points of time. I'm not fluent enoguh in Python+Qt to write the code for the code in your question, but I hope someone does.